# JQM toggle in click event not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

This code works as intenteded in any scenario,

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#page1', function() {
    $(this).on('click', '#search-img', function() {
    alert();
    });
});
```

but toggle() and such methods don't work on next page loaded via JQM ajax

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#page1', function() {
    $(this).on('click', '#search-img', function() {
    $('#search-form').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: where does `$("#search-form")` lie? in `#page1` ? or does it lie in the second page?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same #page1 as a content wrapper for layout for every page.

Comment: can u make a fiddle for this jsfiddle.net?

Comment: if u cant make a fiddle, paste ur code in pastebin.com or post ur html here

Comment: are u using a multi page template?

Comment: same template for every page - http://jsfiddle.net/72qmB/

Comment: do u have ur code in DOM ready?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/72qmB/1/ 
Working now! i think you have ur code in DOM ready..

Comment: not sure, this script lives within heads <script></script>

Comment: copy ur entire code in pastebin.com will you

Comment: it works fine untill I go to next page (which is loaded with jqm ajax thing, thought).

Comment: does the second page also have `#page1` as id?

Comment: yes, same layout with different content via twig template

Comment: pls change the id of that second page..its not supposed to have the same id. jQM will behave erratically if its that way

Comment: both pages uses same layout. How am I suppose to specify ID?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/wN2L9/
THIS is a single page template. This is how ur HTML shud be

Comment: thanks for trying to explain JQM multipage system, but my whole project uses another architecture. It has some base common layouts and content places with templating system with inheritance of templates.

Comment: my god... It's working after I get rid off all id's (use classes instead).

Comment: told ya it'll work :)

Comment: but without id's application can't profit of whole JQM ajax idea...